# Simulating vim's scrolloff in manpages

Tags: man

The issue I have could be illustrated best with example:

I know curl lets me do POST requests but I don't remember how. So I open `man curl`, and begin to search for `POST`. The problem is that every result starts in the middle of some option's description, and I need to scroll (many) lines up to see the command and start of the description.

To be honest, I'm pretty sure searching for the same thing via web would be faster.

To make the process of walking through manpages more comfortable, I have two solutions in mind:

1. Simulate vim's `scrolloff` feature that lets you to keep at least `N` lines above and below currently selected line.
2. Use some other search, that instead of aligning the current line at the highlighted word, will align at the section start.

That way I'll be able to immediately see if the option I look for is relevant or not.

Answer (score 2):

`man` uses `less` internally, and `less` has `-j` option that is almost like `scrolloff` feature (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376360/does-less-have-an-equivalent-to-vims-scrolloff)). Negative values keep the searches at the bottom of the screen.

So if you do `info curl|less -j 4`, you'll be able to search while keeping 4 lines above the text, and if you do `info  curl|less -j -4`, you'll be able to search while keeping 4 lines below the text and "hugging" to the bottom screen edge (I believe this to be more useful.)

Instead of piping `info` to `less` manually, you can make your `man` do it as well by defining a environment variables for `less` (see [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/35887/how-can-you-set-the-r-in-your-less-environment-variable)) - namely, `LESS=-j4` will make `less` use `-j4` by default. If you don't want to pollute the environment, you can make a function for `man` like this:

```
man() {
    env LESS=-j-4 man "$@"
}
```

This will cause it to run in a subshell so the variable will be cleared out.